# How to create a link to open raphael graph in own browser in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

If I have a page for a raphael.js draw in `<div id='my-canvas'></div>`

```
<body> 
  <div id='part_one'>...</div> 
  <div id='my-canvas'></div> 
  <div id='part_three'>...</div> 
  <a href="#"> //Create a link here to open the raphael graph ( at 
<div id=`my-canvas`>) in own browser 
</body>
```

My raphael draw:

```
var paper = Raphael("my-canvas", 320, 200); 
var c = paper.rect(40, 40, 50, 50, 10); 
...
```

I would like to create a link on the page, when user click on the
link, the raphael graph at `<div id='my-canvas'>` will be opened in own
browser, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can put your Raphael.js code into a script which you push into a new window like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickOpen() {
    var mywin = 
        window.open('', 'name', 'height=240,width=360,status=0');
    mywin.document.write(
        '<html><head><title>My Raphael Window</title></head><body>' +
        '<div id="part_one">...</div>' + 
        '<div id="my-canvas"></div>' +
        '<div id="part_three">...</div>' +
        '<script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"><' + '/script>' +
        '<script src="http://yandex.st/raphael/1.5.2/raphael.min.js"><' + '/script>' +
        '<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael_draw.js"><' + '/script>' +
        '</body></html>');
    mywin.document.close();
}
</script>

<button onclick="clickOpen()">Click me</button>
```

However, popup blockers will complain, so I'd use a dialog or lightbox on the same page if possible.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, there is a window popped up, but the raphael elements are not showing in the  pop up window, that's the canvas is empty in the pop up...

Answer (score 0):

Links in new windows (even when an id is the href) make a new URL request *to the server*- like `http://the-page-you-started-on/#my-canvas` which will reload the page you are on and find that specified `id` from the hash value.  I'm not sure how this fits into the HTML specs but a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/Estqe/) showed this behavior.

So you would need to rethink your strategy a little and create a new *page* that has the drawing in it.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I didn't add much there... might need more coffee :). I guess I was trying to say you should look at doing this server-side if you really require a new page to open.  @Oleg's JS insertion idea is more relevant, and I'd also agree with his suggestion that you look at in-page display strategies instead of opening a new window.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @peteorpeter - we can all use a cuppa right now :)